# How to implement video call in iOS using pjsip2.0

Tags: video, ios4, sip, pjsip

We want to implement Video call in iOS using pjsip 2.0. We know that pjsip 2.0 does not support video call in iOS. So what we are planning to implement to whole video call display using iOS native API.

I want to know is it possible? Will pjsip give us video data so that we can pass it directly to iOS native video API. Is there something we have to do to integrate Audio also.

Is there any link available for the same?

Any clue will be great help.

Answer (score 0):

[siphon](http://code.google.com/p/siphon/) has done it, you can find his instructions [here](http://code.google.com/p/siphon/wiki/VIdeoSupport).  It's missing bits so you will have to come up with missing bits yourself.

You basically need two main bits of code:

1. Video capture code that feeds into pjsip video io pipeline.
2. Display code that displays the video feeds coming out of pjsip.